# JavaFX: Stretching Tabs to fit parent TabPane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I'm using the following code to make the combined tab width of the TabPane **fit** the TabPane's width.

```
private void initTabPane() {

    // Populate Tabs
    List<Tab> tabs = _tabPane.getTabs();
    tabs.add(new Tab("Metadator", _metadatorView));
    tabs.add(new Tab("Translator", _translatorView));
    tabs.add(new Tab("ESPN"));

    // Stretch to fit width 
    _tabPane.tabMinWidthProperty().bind(_tabPane.widthProperty()
                                                .divide(_tabPane.getTabs().size())                                                   );
}
```

I'm stuck trying to remove the **tab-down-button view** that shows up when the tabs reach a certain width relative to the TabPane's width. You can see in on the top right corner of the image below:

[image]

I tried playing with padding/margin/bg-color properties of its classes `.control-buttons-tab, .container, .tab-down-button, .arrow` but nothing worked.

> Is there any way to remove it, or offset it far away that it isn't **interfering** with the last tab?

Comment: Can't you account for it within the stretch to fit width bind?

Comment: @Sedrick I could, but i'm trying to make the last tab touch the right side of the window.

Comment: I gave your question an upvote in hopes that it will draw more experienced programmers to the thread.

Answer (score 1):

This is on the right track, but you have to alter it some. You basically need to set the `Tabs'` width to a certain length. Then you need to set the `TabPane's` width to the length of all your `Tabs` added together. Finally, add a little buffer so that the drop-down does not show up. -> see `+55` in the code.

```
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tabs");
        Group root = new Group();

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        List<Tab> tabs = tabPane.getTabs();
        tabs.add(new Tab("Metadator"));
        tabs.add(new Tab("Translator"));
        tabs.add(new Tab("ESPN"));

        tabPane.tabMinWidthProperty().set(100);//set the tabPane's tabs min and max widths to be the same.
        tabPane.tabMaxWidthProperty().set(100);//set the tabPane's tabs min and max widths to be the same.
        System.out.println(tabPane.tabMinWidthProperty().get());
        tabPane.setMinWidth((100 * tabPane.getTabs().size()) + 55);//set the tabPane's minWidth and maybe max width to the tabs combined width + a padding value
        tabPane.setPrefWidth((100 * tabPane.getTabs().size()) + 55);//set the tabPane's minWidth and maybe max width to the tabs combined width + a padding value
        borderPane.setCenter(tabPane);
        root.getChildren().add(borderPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, (100 * tabPane.getTabs().size()) + 55, 250, Color.WHITE);//You might need to set the scene's with also
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time sedrick, but the real issue is that i don't want the buffer. Wish there was a way to delegate the logic of the top tight button to a context menu for example, and just get rid of it.

Comment: You are probably going to have to check when it is present then see if you can hide it.